# Compare Different Columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, statistics, dplyr

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
    State           Rank1     Rank2    Rank3    Rank4
         1          37.20%    32.88%   20.92%   7.02%
         2          44.01%    30.15%   22.68%   1.54%
         3          49.72%    48.86%   47.61%   46.50%
         4          60.40%    30.35%   26.34%   49.78%
```

The data set contains data of last years election of a particular geography. Column A contains the state code and Column B:D contains information about the vote share of top 4 parties in a particular state.

My task is to divide them into 4 category based on certain criterias :

**Unipolar** -  The winner faced no difficulty in getting majority. In most cases like this, the winners cross the half-way mark, i.e. more than 50% of the vote share (VS is used in the dataset.

**Bi-Polar** - The electorates have shown significance indecision in deciding who should get the majority. Runner-up has got substantial votes and there is considerable distance between the runner-up and the 3rd contestant.

**Multi-polar** - Typically multiple contestants have got substantial votes and even minor swing in the votes would have resulted in a different outcome.

**Divided-Unipolar** - Winner has got clear mandate but electorates have shown indecision in deciding whom to vote for next. More than 1 contender has got almost similar votes.

How do I do this in *R* as there would be very close comparison among the share of votes. Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: What cutoffs do you want to use for your last three categories? I can't answer your question without knowing what you mean by things like "indecision."

Comment: What have you tried?  This really sounds like an assignment that you copied and pasted into the question with minimal effort to solve it on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data.frame for your votes :

```
votes = data.frame(State = c(1:4),  Rank1 =  c(37.20, 44.01, 49.72, 60.40), 
Rank2 = c(32.88, 30.15, 48.86, 30.35), 
Rank3 = c(20.92, 22.68, 47.61, 26.34), 
Rank4 = c(7.02, 1.54, 46.50, 49.78))
```

Then use library `dplyr` to use the function `case_when`.

for exemple

```
library(dplyr)
votes$type = case_when(
 votes$Rank1 > unipolar_limit | votes$Rank1 - votes$Rank2 > unipolar_limit2 ~ "Unipolar"
 , votes$Rank2 - votes$Rank3 > bipolar_limit ~ "Bipolar"
 , votes$Rank1 - votes$Rank3 < multi_limit  ~ "Multi-polar"
 , votes$Rank1 > 50 & votes$Rank2 - votes$Rank4 < divided_limit ~ "Divided-Unipolar" 
)
```

Something like that with the limit or conditions you like.